# Telerik's Kendo Grid component with GridEditMode.Popup and TemplateName specified

Tags: c#, telerik, kendo-grid

I have a view that looks like this:

```
@model Wellbore
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<WellboreSection>()
        .Name("wellboresectiongrid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(p => p.Name);
            columns.Bound(p => p.Lenght);
            columns.Bound(p => p.SectionNumber);
            columns.Bound(p => p.Volume);
            columns.Bound(p => p.HoleDiameter);
            columns.Command(command =>
            {
                command.Edit();
                command.Destroy();
            }).Width(240);
        })
        .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
        .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).TemplateName("WellboreSectionPopupTemplate"))
        .Sortable()
        .Scrollable()
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .PageSize(10)
            .Events(events => events.Error("KendoGrid.ErrorHandler"))
            .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.Id))
            .Create(create => create.Action("WellboreSection_Create", "WellboreSection",
                new RouteValueDictionary(new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "wellboreId", Model.Id } })))
            .Read(read => read.Action("WellboreSection_Read", "WellboreSection",
                    new RouteValueDictionary(new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "wellboreId", Model.Id } })))
            .Update(update => update.Action("WellboreSection_Update", "WellboreSection",
                    new RouteValueDictionary(new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "wellboreId", Model.Id } })))
            .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("WellboreSection_Destroy", "WellboreSection",
                    new RouteValueDictionary(new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "wellboreId", Model.Id } })))
      ))
```

And a WellboreSectionPopupTemplate.cshtml file that looks like this:

```
@model WellboreSection
blaaaaah!!!
```

Still, when i click edit in the grid, a popup with all the fields to the object is displayed.

What is really confusing me is that i have another grid that looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 sl-table">
            @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Customer>()
                  .Name("grid")
                  .Columns(columns =>
                  {
                      columns.Bound(p => p.Name);
                      columns.Bound(p => p.StreetAddress);
                      columns.Bound(p => p.ZipCode);
                      columns.Bound(p => p.City);
                      columns.Bound(p => p.State);
                      columns.Bound(p => p.Country);
                      columns.Bound(p => p.MainPhoneNumber);
                      columns.Bound(p => p.ContactPerson);
                      columns.Bound(p => p.ContactPersonEmail);
                      columns.Bound(p => p.ContactPersonPhone);
                      columns.Bound(p => p.ContactPersonPhone2);
                      columns.Command(command =>
                      {
                          command.Edit();
                          command.Destroy();
                      }).Width(180);
                  })
                  .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
                  .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).TemplateName("CustomerPopUpTemplate"))
                  .Pageable()
                  .Sortable()
                  .Scrollable()
                  .HtmlAttributes(new {style = "height:500px;"})
                  .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                      .Ajax()
                      .PageSize(10)
                              .Events(happening => happening.Error("KendoGrid.ErrorHandler"))
                      .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.Id))
                      .Create(update => update.Action("EditingPopup_Create", "CustomerManagement"))
                      .Read(read => read.Action("EditingPopup_Read", "CustomerManagement"))
                      .Update(update => update.Action("EditingPopup_Update", "CustomerManagement"))
                      .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("EditingPopup_Destroy", "CustomerManagement"))))
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Which actually displays the template 100% correct. I have checked the browser, and it does not call for WellboreSectionPopupTemplate when i click the edit or add new button in the grid. What could i possibly be missing?

- If more information is needed, just ask, and i will gladly provide :)

Comment: It looks like things are named right. Is the editor template in the proper location? http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-3-default-templates.html

You might also compare with the example here, see if anything stands out: http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/custom-popup-editor

Comment: It was the proper location kinda thing that was wrong... Thanks so much for helping me figuring it out.. If you would like to have the accepted answer, create an answer, and i'll mark it

Comment: Looks like we both encountered the same problem on a grid displaying Well Borehole data. How bizarre!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When creating custom templates in MVC they have the be placed in a certain spot.

The locations searched are:

- /Areas/AreaName/Views/ControllerName/EditorTemplates/TemplateName
- /Areas/AreaName/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/TemplateName
- /Views/ControllerName/EditorTemplates/TemplateName
- /Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/TemplateName

Display template paths would be the same, just with a /DispayTemplates/ in the path instead of /EditorTemplates/

Template names also have to match convention:

- TemplateHint from ModelMetadata
- DataTypeName from ModelMetadata
- The name of the type
- If the object is not complex: “String”
- If the object is complex and an interface: “Object”
- If the object is complex and not an interface: Recurse through the inheritance hiearchy for the type, trying every type name

source: http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-3-default-templates.html